# vswprintf crashes

Tags: c++, symbian, posix

using the Symbian S60 5th edition SDK released on October 2nd, I am compiling/running(on sim) the following code snippet:

```
void test(wchar_t *dest, int size, const wchar_t *fmt, ...) {
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, fmt);
    vswprintf(dest, size, fmt, vl);
    va_end(vl);
}

...

wchar_t str[1024];

// this crashes (2nd string 123 characters (+ \0) equals 248 bytes)
test(str, 1024, L"msg: %S", L"this is a test messagethis is a test messagethis is a test messagethis is a test messagethis is a test messagethis is a tes");

// this works (2nd string 122 characters (+ \0) equals 246 bytes)
test(str, 1024, L"msg: %S", L"this is a test messagethis is a test messagethis is a test messagethis is a test messagethis is a test messagethis is a te");
```

For no reason obvious to me (even after having read the [vswprintf](http://www.forum.nokia.com/document/CDL_Extension_S60_3rd_Ed_FP2/GUID-719955DA-415B-420E-9F9B-F6DB37615EC5/html/wprintf.html) man page a hundred times) can I figure out why this code is crashing on me in the vswprintf call for long strings :-( The exact same code works fine on a Linux box. There is sufficient memory allocated for str, plus vswprintf is checking for buffer overruns anyway. Unfortunately the ... S60 debugger does not break on this crash, so I have no details :-(

Does anybody have any ideas?

Assuming a bug in Symbian's vswprintf routine, what would be possible replacement functions using POSIX compliant code? (this is supposed to be a cross-platform library)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like a job for stepping into the `vswprintf()` call.  Even if you can only do assembly-level debugging, it should be clear what's more or less going on by keeping a watch on what's going into the the `str[]` memory.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to find an internal buffer inside vswprintf's implementation to be hard-coded to 128 bytes. This could very well cause such a crash on long strings.

Answer (score 0):

Change the %S to a %s - uppercase to lowercase.

In MS-based printfs, %S means unicode characters, so this is why the 123 character string fails, it expects 2 bytes per character. (note %S is not part of the standard, so Symbian may be different here)

Actually, I think that still applies to [Symbian](http://www.symbian.com/developer/techlib/v70sdocs/doc_source/reference/cpp/Descriptors/FormatStringSyntax.guide.html#Descriptors.Format-string-syntax).

Comment: No, he wants %S (which is equivalent to %ls) - the L prefix before the string constants makes them wide-character string constants.

Comment: Adam ist right, the standard says %s=char*, %S=wchar_t*. MS screwed this up by making %s be TCHAR and %S !TCHAR, hence the confusion. %S is actually correct here. Even if it weren't, it wouldn't cause a crash (just the string to be one character long only).

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the `%S` format specifier to `%ls`.  As mentioned in my earlier comment, they're supposed to be equivalent, but there could be a bug in the implementation.  Note that the `vswprintf` function is defined in the C99 standard, and since there are not yet any fully conforming C99 compilers (I believe), it's very possible that any given implementation of `vswprintf` does not fully conform to the spec, or that it contains bugs (the former is more likely than the latter).

Comment: The Symbian docs (see link in question) actually mention %S. Nonetheless it's worth a try ... unfortunately it doesn't change the situation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try not calling test() and using swprintf instead -- in case the bug has to do with VARARGS handling?

Comment: Using swprintf does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've now "solved" this problem by using Symbian functions to perform this task:

```
void test(wchar_t *dest, int size, const wchar_t *fmt, ...) {
    VA_LIST args;
    VA_START(args, fmt);

    TPtrC16 fmtPtr((const TUint16*)fmt, wcslen(fmt) + 1);  
    TPtr16  targetPtr((TUint16*)dest, size);

    targetPtr.FormatList(fmtPtr, args);
    targetPtr.ZeroTerminate();

    VA_END(args);
}
```

(in which case you actually have to [use %s](http://www.symbian.com/Developer/techlib/v9.1docs/doc_source/guide/Base-subsystem-guide/N10086/BuffersAndStrings/Descriptors/DescriptorsGuide3/FormatStringSyntax.guide.html))